# summming up from 3 tables and group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Im a beginner to sql and want to take these 3 tables' Price to put it on a new column in a 4th table (PC) as total, so far i got to sum, but it just takes every single price and sum it all to a single value, and even deletes every other column. again, i have just a very basic understanding of what im doing.

```
Select SUM(monitor.Preco + gabinete.Preco + teclado.Preco) AS 'Total'
from monitor, gabinete, teclado;
GROUP BY monitor.ID;
```

i cant get the group by to work i keep saying error in sql syntax. help

My PC table calls in those other 3 tables ID like this:

```
        ID  |  M  |  G  |  T  |  Total  | - The total should be like this
        1   |  1  |  1  |  1  | 0000000 |
```

instead my PC table does this when i put the command above:

```
       Total  | - i want it to show the total for each row.      
       999999 |
```

Comment: Learn to `JOIN` before you try `GROUP BY`.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: ok but i already have the ID | M | G | T  columns how would i join in a Total columns?

Comment: First off how do you know what is the spec for your PC i.e. which combination creates a valid combination that you want to get a total price for.  Is it that in your PC table, does PC have fields like monitor_Id, gabinete_Id, teclado_Id and are they already populated?  If not do you want all combinations - note this can result in a large number of records

Comment: yeah i got id_monitor, id_teclado and id_gabinete as foreign keys in the PC table those form the columns M, T, G

Comment: Learn how to use `SUM()`.  That' not how it works.

Comment: Since you pretty much know nothing about `SQL`, start simple.  Don't start with `GROUP BY`.  Do you even know what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT pc.M, pc.G, pc.T, (monitor.Preco + gabinete.Preco + teclado.Preco) AS 'Total'
FROM pc
INNER JOIN monitor ON pc.M = monitor.Id
INNER JOIN gabinete ON pc.G = gabinete.Id
INNER JOIN teclado ON pc.T = teclado.Id
```

I'll leave it to you to convert the SELECT into an UPDATE statement to update the Total in the PC table